# Drupal 7 print.less editing issue

Tags: css, drupal

Drupal 7

Bootstrap module installed to sites/all/libraries/bootstrap/

I'm running into an issue editing the CSS style for page printing. When looking at the css through Chrome dev tools it shows a css file:  sites/all/libraries/bootstrap/css/less/print.less, however this file does not exist. It is adding a CSS style that I can't unset and I need it changed. When I grep for the css causing me issues it turns up in: sites/all/libraries/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css.map, but when I edit the CSS in that file it does not change.

I have cleared the cache using the button in development > performance and using drush cc all, but the CSS does not update.

I have also tried adding the less/print.less folder/file in hopes it would override, but to no success.

The specific CSS causing me problems is this:

`*,
    *:before,
    *:after {
        background: transparent !important;
        color: #000 !important; // Black prints faster: h5bp.com/s
        box-shadow: none !important;
        text-shadow: none !important;
    }`

The !important tag on background is messing me all up.

If anyone could tip me off as to how to edit print.less I'd be much obliged.

Comment: Drupal bootstrap is a theme, not a module. It should live in the sites/all/themes folder. You should create a subtheme of the bootstrap theme instead of using the theme directly. The Drupal Bootstrap theme has it's [own documentation page](https://drupal-bootstrap.org/api/bootstrap)